# Flask app with Apache2 Can Not Find Paths

Tags: python, linux, apache, server, ubuntu-server

I deployed my flask application on Ubuntu VPS Server 18.04 with Apache 2 but the server can not find the paths excluding `/static`. Every route my application is being down because of these paths fail and I don't know what to do. Here is my server conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName <ServerName >
                ServerAdmin <ServerAdmin>
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Do i need to add anything else to the conf? To see my folders?

By the way, the tree is;

```
FlaskApp
├── FlaskApp
│   ├── pycache
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── categories [CONTAINS JSON FILES]
│   │   ├── details [CONTAINS JSON FILES]
│   │   └── products [CONTAINS JSON FILES]
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── categories
│   │   │   ├── details
│   │   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── logo
│   │   │   ├── products
│   │   │   └── special
│   │   │       ├── products
│   │   │       └── references
│   │   └── js
│   └── templates
│       ├── admin
│       ├── security
│       ├── special
│       │   └── tools
│       └── tools
└── venv
└── flaskapp.wsgi
```

flaskapp.wsgi;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = '<secret_key>'
```

and here is one of the errors I get;

```
[Tue Sep 29 13:55:27.099228 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 25676] [client "address"] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/categories/categories.json', referer: "address"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to add the full path in wsgi file?
`sys.path.insert(0,"fullpath")`
update: the same for apache file

Comment: @archer Do you mean conf file by the same for apache file? And how?

Comment: In <VirtualHost *:80>--->Directory in the code you added in your question

Comment: @archer Im not sure how to do that exactly. Can you give me a code example? Thanks

Comment: This is the path of a healthy running flask app:

`<Directory "C:/Users/Administrator/apps/appname">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>`

Comment: In place of your code piece above:
`<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>`

Comment: Add the wsgi path:
`sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\apps\\appname')`

Comment: @archer I have tried everything you told me but it still can't find the paths

Comment: try to add directories in double quotes in apache
`<Directory "C:/Users/Administrator/apps/appname"> etc`

Comment: @archer that doesnt work either :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222260/discussion-between-ykerem-and-archer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add `os.getcwd()` or `os.path.abspath(".")` to all paths prefix.